# How to dynamicly load files with TypoScript

Tags: dynamic, typo3, typoscript, critical-css

I want to load for every page the riht criticalCSS File.

So I saved them like this:

fileadmin/critical1.css for `TSFE:id=1`

fileadmin/critical2.css for `TSFE:id=2`

and so on. As there are a lot of pages I want the TS to be completely dynamic and NOT like this:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id=1]
page {
  cssInline {
    10 = FILE
    10.file = fileadmin/critical1.css
  }
}
[global]
```

I want it like this:

```
page {
  cssInline {
    10 = FILE
    10.file= fileadmin/critical{page:uid}.css
  }
}
```

or this

```
page {
  cssInline {
    10 = FILE
    10.file= fileadmin/critical$GLOBALS['TSFE']->id.css
  }
}
```

But it is not working like this. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the `insertData = 1`.

Check this code :

```
page {
  cssInline {
    10 = FILE
    10.file= fileadmin/critical{page:uid}.css
    10.file.insertData = 1 
  }
}
```

Reference : 
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap.html?highlight=insertdata#insertdata

---

Alternatively you can achieve it using `headerData`.

Check this code :

```
page {
  headerData {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value = {page:uid}
    10.insertData = 1 
    10.wrap = <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fileadmin/critical|.css" media="all" />
  }
}
```

Reference : https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#headerdata

Hope this helps you!